# Is it able to inject RequestScope bean into Singleton bean using Constructor Injection in Spring?

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection, scope, requestscope

It is working as far as I tested. But I do not get it why and how it works.(Also I am not sure it is safe to use in production)

Here is my testCode

```
@Service
public class SomeService {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SomeService.class);

    private final RequestContext requestContext; // @RequestScope + @Component Bean
    public SomeService(RequestContext requestContext) {
        this.requestContext = requestContext;
    }

    public void checkBean() {
        logger.info("Singleton Bean: {}, RequestScope Bean: {}", this, this.requestContext);
        String clientId = recommendContext.getClientId();
    }
}
```

The Scenario like below

- Get a Request from Controller
- `SomeService` is injected by Controller
- Every request has its own `RequestContext` Bean
- In Controller, call `someService.checkBean()`

The point I think strange is

- `SomeService` is a singleton bean
- `RequestContext` is declared as a `final` variable and only initiated by constructor
- However it seems works.

The result of running code looks like below

```
2021-06-14 09:56:26.010 INFO  23075 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] p.service.SomeService   : Singleton Bean: pkgs.service.SomeServiceImpl@3c65ee26, RequestScope Bean: pkgs.context.RequestContext@56867592
2021-06-14 09:56:30.933 INFO  23075 --- [nio-8888-exec-3] p.service.SomeService   : Singleton Bean: pkgs.service.SomeServiceImpl@3c65ee26, RequestScope Bean: pkgs.context.RequestContext@73ddb7a4
2021-06-14 09:56:31.687 INFO  23075 --- [nio-8888-exec-4] p.service.SomeService   : Singleton Bean: pkgs.service.SomeServiceImpl@3c65ee26, RequestScope Bean: pkgs.context.RequestContext@56b4f7c8
2021-06-14 09:56:32.352 INFO  23075 --- [nio-8888-exec-5] p.service.SomeService   : Singleton Bean: pkgs.service.SomeServiceImpl@3c65ee26, RequestScope Bean: pkgs.context.RequestContext@33469287
```

As you can see Service is Single and RequestContext bean is unique for every request.
I need some explanation of what is going on inside spring

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a bean is request-scoped, Spring creates a proxy. Whenever this proxy is called, it delegates to an instance of the bean that is specific to the current request.

In your case, the `RequestContext` instance that is injected into `SomeService` and stored in the `requestContext` `final` variable is the proxy. If you tried to call the service outside the scope of a web request it would fail as the proxy would not be able to find the current request.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the proxy type in your bean definition
ref: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes

```
@Bean
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public HelloMessageGenerator requestScopedBean() {
    return new HelloMessageGenerator();
}
```